# Can an iphone app add music to itunes?

Tags: iphone, itunes

Is it possible for an iphone app to directly add content to itunes, either directly on the phone, or by automatically (i.e. no user actions required) syncing when the iphone is connected to a computer?

If not, what is the fall back? One suggestion what was made to me is that the user can drag and drop files from the apps' Documents folder into the Music folder.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's no way to do that without using private APIs. I'd enable UIFileSharing and let the user email the audio file, so they may add it manually.

Comment: Dude that's crazy I did a search and the link I clicked on was one of your posts on sensitivecode:

[link](http://www.sensitivecode.com/site/2011/01/29/documents-folder-and-uifilesharing/)

Could you elaborate on your comments about "e-mailing the file" ... 

Here's a basic user story:

1) User uses iPhone app to download content into the App
2) User connects iPhone to computer
3) User uses iTunes to view the content stored in the apps and transfer it into iTunes

So I'm not clear how the e-mailing would fit into that.

Comment: You could create a button in your app that would let the user email the file by using MFMailComposeViewController